# BVH trees - ways to determine child nodes intersection order?

Tags: raytracing

just to mention that my math skills are not great and i need to ask for a little help here !

I am now trying to implement a stack less BVH traversal function using this paper:
https://graphics.cg.uni-saarland.de/fileadmin/cguds/papers/2011/hapala_sccg2011/hapala_sccg2011.pdf

I am having it working except i am likely not having the both child traversal order correct which results in wrong image.

In point ( 3 Algorithm outline ) they mention a couple of methods to determine the right order:

> For the traversal order there are various different alternatives. One
>   often-used option is to store, for each node, the coordinate axis
>   along which the builder split the parent node, and to use the ray’s
>   direction sign in this dimension to determine the two nodes’ traversal
>   order.

Let's say i am having the split axis index as 0, 1, 2 for X, Y, Z and the ray direction... It can determine the split axis by computing the maximum separation axis of both nodes centroids on the fly which i am also having...

**So, the question is what would be the way (math) to determine the nodes traversal order by using the ray direction and the split axis ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> use the ray’s direction sign in this dimension to determine the two nodes’ traversal order.

Suppose your ray has direction `(0.707, 0, -0.707)`.

For that ray:

If you determine the parent's split axis to be `X` (i.e. two children share a boundary on the `YZ` plane), then your ray's direction sign in `X` is positive (`0.707`), and you should traverse the child whose centroid has the higher `X` centroid coordinate first.

If you determine the parent's split axis to by `Y` (i.e. two children share a boundary on the `XZ` plane), then your ray's direction in `Y` is unsigned (`0`) and you'll have to decide what to do. The details of what you do in this case are up to you (pick a direction, move on to the next coordinate, etc) but acting consistently is the key.

If you determine the parent's split axis to be `Z` (i.e. to children share a boundary on the `XY` plane), then your ray's direction in `Z` is negative (`-.707`), and you should traverse the child whose centroid has the lower `Z` coordinate first.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer - this is working for me. Just tested !

Comment: I might have it backwards, actually - i.e. if the direction coord is positive, you want to traverse the lower centroid child first, and vice versa.

Comment: May be yes, it should work in both cases, the only difference is that the count of the traversed nodes will differ a little ( at least i guess so ) - i haven't tested the performance in both cases though. Should do it !